# SSL Certificate Error: certificate_unknown

Tags: iphone, push-notification, ssl-certificate, apple-push-notifications, provider

while creating push notification provider for development pr we are facing the below error:
I want to what is the wrong with certificate, because I have enabled the push notification then created the certificate but I am getting certificate_unknown error?

```
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, certificate_unknown
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
Error pushing notification(s):
Invalid certificate chain (Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown)!  Verify that the keystore you provided was produced according to specs...
      at javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager.sendNotification(PushNotificationManager.java:359)
      at javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager.sendNotification(PushNotificationManager.java:301)
      at javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager.sendNotification(PushNotificationManager.java:258)
      at javapns.Push.payload(Push.java:122)
      at javapns.Push.alert(Push.java:36)
      at com.applicationname.pns.PushNotification.main(PushNotification.java:31)
```

//my code which I am using for push notification

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.applicationname.pns;

import org.json.JSONException;

import javapns.Push;
import javapns.devices.Device;
import javapns.notification.Payload;
import javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager;
import javapns.notification.PushNotificationPayload;


public class PushNotification
{
    private static final String HOST = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";
    private static final int PORT = 2195;
    private static final int BADGE = 66;
    private static String iPhoneId = "5696ee2fa44c61fd21a7987d2b1bcf57faa1603e63cb57ff204b158fb90d28a3";
    private static String certificate = "D:/./trunk/Development/JavaPNS/src/com/applicationname/pns/privateKey.p12";
    private static String passwd = "password@1234";

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Push.alert("Hello World!", certificate, passwd, false,iPhoneId);

        PushNotificationPayload payLoad = new PushNotificationPayload();

        try
        {
            payLoad.addAlert("Hello World!");
            payLoad.addBadge(10);
        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: I have added the source code.

Comment: You get a `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException` but your code doesn't seem to include any networking. Are you certain the exception occurs with exactly the code you pasted?

Answer (score 2):

Try to load the public key in place of privatekey

```
private static String certificate = "D:/./trunk/Development/JavaPNS/src/com/applicationname/pns/privateKey.p12";
```

The private key is loaded by the SSL socket on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure to follow the [procedure](http://code.google.com/p/javapns/wiki/PreparingCertificates) for preparing certificates documented on the official JavaPNS web site.  Developers that follow this procedure get positive results.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue in jdk 1.7 and using p12, just after changing the passwd length of p12 file greater than or equal 6. Otherwise, the following error happens:
[[1] not transmitted to token 595d8..725bf  javapns.communication.exceptions.InvalidCertificateChainException: Invalid certificate chain (Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown)!  Verify that the keystore you provided was produced according to specs...]